# Microsoft Teams App Live Share Recording Support Status

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I have a question about recording for the Live Share Teams App, we tried to record our meeting but when we started the recording we got this message, and the recorded result does not include our Microsoft Teams app.

[image]

Then we take a look in the faq https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/apps-in-teams-meetings/teams-live-share-faq it says that this feature is not available yet. My question is when this feature will be available because we need to record all the activity in our Microsoft Teams app. If you guys give us an estimation that will be so helpful because we need to use this feature for one of our customers.

Answer (score 0):

Currently we do not have any specific deadline for this feature, but you can raise your feature request here and track it: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472

Also, you can get latest Teams platform updates by subscribing to the RSS feed:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/whats-new?pivots=ga-feature

Comment: Thanks for your answer, because the message says coming soon I thought you guys had a specific date.  I already raised a feature I hope it coming soon.